# Integral inequality with absolute value and switch of the integration variable

Tags: integration, inequality, absolute-value

What is the rule/theorem/inequality that can be applied to this integral:

$$
\int_a^b {d^k \over dt^k}x(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}\,df
$$
so that I can write this inequality ?

$$
\left\lvert\int_a^b {d^k \over dt^k}x(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}\,df\right\rvert\leq\int_a^b \left | {d^k \over dt^k}x(t)\right | dt
$$

I found this inequality (I don't know if it has a specific name):

$$
\left\lvert\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right\rvert\leq\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert dx
$$

However this doesn't explain to me the switch from $dt$ to $df$ in the right member of the inequality.

NOTE: The $j$ in the integral is instead the the equivalent of the imaginary unity $i$ for complex valued functions.

Comment: That particular inequality you found is often referred to as the triangle inequality. Are you sure you wrote everything down correctly? If you are integrating with respect to $df$, then $d^kx/dt^k$ comes right out of the integral.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thanks I didn't know that this version of __triangle inequality__ existed. Yes the inequality that I wrote is correct, no typo or mistake. Ok I can switch the integral and the differentiation but I don't see how this can help me. I believe we can't use the Liebniz integral rule here.